# Отображение в верхнем регистре

Tags: javascript

Как с помощью javascript сделать так, чтобы при нажатии клавиши в нижнем регистре в другом элементе она отображалась как большая буква?

Comment: вам нужно чтобы текст на элементе всегда отображался большими буквами? Тогда можно воспользоваться css свойством `text-transform: uppercase;`

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function(){
  $(document).on('input', '.input', function(){
    $('.result').html($(this).val().toUpperCase());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Текст с маленкой буквы"/>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Метод `String.toUpperCase()` служит для перевода букв в верхний регистр.